# AngularJS Components: Opposite of "callback" binding?

Tags: angularjs

Sometimes an AngularJS custom component benefits from having a method to trigger a particular behavior. A generic example might be to trigger a reset of the component to an initial state. But it doesn't seem like AngularJS has a clean way to implement this functionality. The approaches I can think of all seem less than ideal.

#### 1. Add a method to the DOM element itself (not the component) and call it directly in the parent

In the component

```
$ctrl.$postLink = function () {
    $element[0].reset = $ctrl.doReset;
```

In the parent

```
$element.find("my-component")[0].reset();
```

#### 2. Use a one-way binding and "fake" a change

In the component

```
bindings: {
    tiggerReset: "<"
```

and

```
$ctrl.$onChanges = function (changes) {
    if (changes.triggerReset && ! changes.triggerReset.isFirstChange())
        $ctrl.doReset();
```

In the parent

```
<my-component trigger-reset="$ctrl.triggerComponentReset" />
```

and

```
$ctrl.triggerComponentReset = new String("true");
```

(note that a new string must be constructed so that AngularJS thinks that the binding has changed.)

#### 3. Access the controller directly from the parent

In the parent

```
$element.find("my-component").controller("myComponent").doReset();
```

It seems like there must be a more idiomatic and/or elegant approach that I'm missing.